# error while compiling kernel

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, compiling

while I was compiling the kernel it suddenly started giving me these errors

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/tdls.o: file not recognized: File truncated

scripts/Makefile.build:530: recipe for target 'drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.o' failed

make[6]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:558: recipe for target 'drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm' failed

make[5]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:558: recipe for target 'drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi' failed

make[4]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:558: recipe for target 'drivers/net/wireless/intel' failed

make[3]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/intel] Error 2

make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

scripts/Makefile.build:558: recipe for target 'drivers/net/wireless' failed

make[2]: *** [drivers/net/wireless] Error 2

scripts/Makefile.build:558: recipe for target 'drivers/net' failed

make[1]: *** [drivers/net] Error 2

Makefile:1033: recipe for target 'drivers' failed

make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

---

### the output of ( sudo lshw -C network ) is

*-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface

   product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller

   vendor: Intel Corporation

   physical id: 3

   bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0

   logical name: enp0s3

   version: 02

   serial: 08:00:27:82:8c:92

   size: 1Gbit/s

   capacity: 1Gbit/s

   width: 32 bits

   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.0.2.15 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:19 memory:f0000000-f001ffff ioport:d010(size=8)
```

---

what should I do

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! tell me what the kernel and Ubuntu version your have?

Comment: the kernel "version is 4.15.0-34-generic"

Comment: the ubuntu version is 18.04.1

Comment: Why did you feel that you need to compile an older version of *iwlwifi* than is already included in Ubuntu 18.04? Are you having wireless trouble that we can help you with? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: tell me what the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and edit your question with that output

Comment: I actually have a HW where i was supposed to add a system call then recompile the kernel and this error appeared

Comment: Please give us a link to the driver file you are trying to compile. Or are you trying to recompile the kernel source itself??

Comment: the kernel source

Comment: for the one who asked about the output of sudo lshw -C network do you want me to add the output to the question ??

Comment: "`drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/tdls.o: file not recognized: File truncated`" is your disk full, or out of inodes?

Comment: The system i am working on is a vertual machine it has 22 out of 42 gb free